# Custom facebook share

Tags: php, html, facebook, button, share

I cannot change the parameters in the sharing screen. I would like to change the title, description and image, follow my example.

Php:

```
<?php
     $title = "My Title";
     $description = "My Description";
     $url = "http://cartolaleague.com.br";
     $image = "http://cartolaleague.com.br/imagens/rodapeEscudo.png";
?>
```

HTML:

```
<a class="btn" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo urlencode( "$title" ); ?> &amp;p[summary]=<?php echo urlencode( "$description" )  ?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo urlencode( "$url" ); ?>&amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo urlencode( "$link" );  ?>">Share on Facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via HTML meta tags

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title;?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $description;?>
```

a complete list of Open Graph tags are given here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/checklist/

You can use the debug tool to fix what you want:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I'm use, but don't work

<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.cartolaleague.com.br" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.cartolaleague.com.br" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Math website for your gifted student" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Challenging word problems for gifted elementary students" />

Comment: Have you tried using the debug tool? It would show you what is missing.

Im assuming you're using the meta tags correctly in your html header